# EF Core one to many relationships: ICollection or Hashset?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am reading "Entity Framework Core in Action" by Jon P Smith. 
There it says:

[image]

Could you provide some examples when Hashet is a proper collection type? And why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I have just finished updating my book [Entity Framework Core in Action](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15506) and I did some performance tests which shows `HashSet<T>` is quicker if you are doing a normal query (i.e. without `AsNoTracking` in the query). That's because EF Core does something called *Identity Resolution* (read about [this in one of my articles](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/ef-core-in-depth-what-happens-when-ef-core-reads-from-the-database/#1-normal-query-a-read-write-query)), which is slower with non-HashSet collections. So, if you have LOTs of entries in your collections, then `HashSet<T>` is better.

<s>I personally use `ICollection<T>` for normal properties, just because its a well-known interface with minimal overheads, i.e. it is very slightly quicker to create an `ICollection` than a `IList`. You can of course use `HashSet<T>`, which is what EF Core uses, but I find `HashSet`'s are a little harder to set than `ICollection<T>`, which takes a `List<T>`.</s>

The one place you have to use `HashSet<T>` if you are using uninitialized backing field collections - see code below:

```
private HashSet<Review> _reviews;
public IEnumerable<Review> Reviews => _reviews?.ToList();
```

**UPDATE: With EF Core 3 the limitation of having to use `HashSet<T>` for  uninitialized collections has been removed (see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15506)). You can use `ICollection<T>`, `List<T>` etc.**

`IEnumerable<T>` is a special case, because it turns a collection into a read-only version, due to `IEnumerable` not having a `Add` or `Remove` method. Backing fields plus `IEnumerable<T>` (see code above) allows you to "lock down" a collection relationship so that it can only be changed from inside the class (see my article [Domain-Driven Design in EF Core](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/creating-domain-driven-design-entity-classes-with-entity-framework-core/)).

When I use backing field collections I leave them uninitialized, so they need to be `HashSet<T>`. This allows me to detect when I forgot to use .Include when loading an entity, e.g. if I loaded a book without `.Include(p => p.Reviews)` and then accessed the Reviews property I would get a null reference exception. This is just a safe way of programming.

If you initialise a backing field collection then it can be `ICollection` etc., but I don't recommend initialising a backing field collection because it can cause problems if you forget the Include and then add a item to the collection. In that case EF Core deletes any existing reviews and replaces them with the the new one you added. From EF Core's point of view its doing what you said, but its most likely NOT what you intended.

Comment: What about `IEnumerable<T>` ?.

Comment: Added section on `IEnumerable<T>` for Unnamed

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative reply! Could you tell more why you avoid Hashsets in this context: _but I find HashSet's are a little harder set than ICollection<T>, which takes a List<T>_ ?

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis. First I should say this is just a personal preference and using `HashSet<T>` is most likely better. I have always used `ICollection<T>` with EF6 and now EF Core. The specific, but minor, issue is I can assign to a ICollection directly from `List<T>`, but for a `HashSet<T>` needs `new HashSet<T>( ... someList)`.

If you use `HashSet<T>` everywhere then keep doing that.

Comment: The comment about initializing a backing field collection resulting in deleted data doesn't seem to be accurate in the latest version(s) of EF Core (I'm currently using EF 8). Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: @glen-84, are you saying that EF Core NET 8 has a different approach on backing fields? I don't see anything in the [What's New in EF Core 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew). What change have you found?

Comment: @JonPSmith I don't know of any such change, I just wasn't able to reproduce the issue.